# android reading from a file

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and while reading a book can't understand the reason for new allocation in the loop. Isn't it enough to make it once before the loop?

```
        FileInputStream fIn =
                openFileInput("textfile.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new
                InputStreamReader(fIn);
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
        String s = "";
        int charRead;
        while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0)
        {
            //---convert the chars to a String---
            String readString =
            String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0,
            charRead);
            s += readString;
            inputBuffer = new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
        }
```

Comment: just for clarification: the question is why the following line is required in the loop: inputBuffer = new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to allocate the buffer only once so you can just remove the allocation inside the loop and it should work well.

And another thing... This code has a really poor performance because it uses string concatenation in the loop. You should use `StringBuilder.append()` instead of `s += readString`.

P.S. I would recommend you to choose another book because this one has too many errors in such simple code.

Comment: interesting... it's from the book: BEGINNING Android 4 Application Development by Wei-Meng Lee.

Answer (score 3):

From `String.copyValueOf` javadoc :

```
  /**
 * Creates a new string containing the specified characters in the character
 * array. Modifying the character array after creating the string has no
 * effect on the string.
 *
 * @param start
 *            the starting offset in the character array.
 * @param length
 *            the number of characters to use.
```

So there is **no reason** to create a new char[] in the loop.

Comment: downvote? i clicked on the button which said the comment was useful. Really sorry if something went wrong. and thank you again.

Comment: @Leon you didn't downvote but to close an answer you have to tick it (the clear tick sign underneath the votes). Suggest you do that as it encourages people to answer your questions